# google appengine - how to configure to send and receive email

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've googled a lot on this and I dont know what I'm missing. I have a contact form so users can contact me:

**contact.html**

```
<form id="contact" action="" method="post" name="contact">
    <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
    <input id="id_subject" type="text" name="subject" maxlength="100">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input id="id_email" type="text" name="email">
    <label for="message">Message:</label>
    <textarea id="id_message" rows="10" cols="40" name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**app.yaml**

```
inbound_services:
- mail    
- url: /_ah/mail/.+
  script: main.py
  login: admin
```

**main.py**

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from google.appengine.api import mail
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.mail_handlers import InboundMailHandler 

class Contact(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):  
        self.response.out.write(template.render('contact.html', {}))
    def post(self):
        sender = self.request.get("email")
        subject = self.request.get("subject")
        body = self.request.get("message")          
        message = mail.EmailMessage(sender=sender, subject=subject)
        message.to = "myemail@gmail.com"
        message.body = body
        message.send()

class LogSenderHandler(InboundMailHandler):
    def receive(self, mail_message):
        logging.info("Received a message from: " + mail_message.sender)

def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/contact', Contact),  
                                           LogSenderHandler.mapping()],
                                           debug=True)
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The class `LogSenderHandler` doesn't work, the receive() requires an extra argument that i don't know where to get. So I don't comment it out when i deploy.
It's a mess in my head. I don't know how to put it together.
When I tried to email to myself I get this on my dashboard logs:

```
Unauthorized sender
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py", line 703, in __call__
    handler.post(*groups)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~projectname/1.354692671370598794/main.py", line 27, in post
    message.send()
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/mail.py", line 894, in send
    raise ERROR_MAP[e.application_error](e.error_detail)
InvalidSenderError: Unauthorized sender
```

Could you help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send through the email submitted on the form, since you aren't authorized to use that email. You either have to use an email you control or the user's email by connecting to their Google account. http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail.html This page says which email you can use to send emails from, just scroll down right after the first code block.

Answer (score 1):

From the [App Engine docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail.html)

> The email address of the sender, the From address. The sender address
>   must be one of the following types:
>
> - The address of a registered administrator for the application. You can add administrators to an application using the Administration
>     Console.
> - The address of the user for the current request signed in with a Google Account. You      can determine the current user's email address with the Users API. The
>     user's account must be a Gmail account, or be on a domain managed by
>     Google Apps.
> - Any valid email receiving address for the app (such as xxx@APP-ID.appspotmail.com).

So if your sender email id is not one of these, you will get this error.

Comment: how can u get a xxx@APP-ID.appspotmail.com id? and what are xxx and app-id?

Comment: @RajeevS You don't have to do anything. xxx means you can have any word there. APP-ID is the application id you chose when you registered the app. For eg : if you registered test.appspot.com, you're app id is 'test' and you can mail to mail@test.appspotmail.com. You don't have to use 'mail', you can use anything.